# My Sql query for fetcing data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables(in the image file)

Course_Inventory_Tbl

[image]

AND Store_Tbl

[image]

Description:
There is a University with some courses, and For each course university provides material to its student. Each course material have few booklets. 
Store_Table contains information of MaterialAvailablity and that material contains how many booklets.
Course_Inventory_Tbl contains information of Booklets for each courseID how many booklets are available.

So What I have to do is, I am checking for NumberOfBooklets in the Store_Tbl for the ID
and checking for all those CourseID, if BookletAvailabilty is Available then I have to take Min(NumberOfBookletAvailable) and update it to the Course_Inventory_Tbl.NumberOfBookAvailable.
and update Course_Inventory_Tbl.MaterialAvailability to "Available"

Before Updating any column(which is my goal), I am doing preliminary task of selecting the `Course_Inventory_Tbl.CourseID , min(Course_Inventory_Tbl.NumberOfBookletsAvailable)` when course booklet is Available.

Here is my query:

```
select  Course_Inventory_Tbl.CourseID , 
min(Course_Inventory_Tbl.NumberOfBookletsAvailable) 
from Course_Inventory_Tbl , Store_Tbl
where 
Course_Inventory_Tbl.CourseID = Store_Tbl.ID
AND Course_Inventory_Tbl.BookletAvailability = "Available"
group by Course_Inventory_Tbl.CourseID
having Store_Tbl.NumberOfBooklets = count(Course_Inventory_Tbl.ID)
```

This query is not working properly saying `You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression ' Store_Tbl.NumberOfBooklets = count(Course_Inventory_Tbl.ID) ' as a part of an aggregate function.

Please help me through the error as I tried a lot and guide me to achieve my goal. I am using MS Access 2010 as my database.

Thank you

With Regards

Comment: if you're using MS Access why is it tagged MySQL and then not include Access tag?

Comment: @John Ruddell I am building an application in vb.net where I have to use such query and i don't know if it matters to mention query as finally what i an up to is build the query

Answer (score -2):

Please use this mysql query to sorting data and fetch data in mysql.

```
$query = mysql_query("select 
    co.*,
    st.*
    from
    co.Course_Inventory_Tbl,
    st.Store_Tbl
    where 
    st.id=co.CourseID and
    co.BookletAvailability='Available'
    ");
```

Comment: you do realize mysql_* is deprecated right? you should recommend something other than that.. that aside the OP isn't even using php..